Calling a stored procedure from EF Core 8 with Managed Identities
I have developed an Azure Function app that connects to a Azure SQL Server through EF Core 8. I use a system assigned identity.
When connecting to tables etc everything goes as expected. But when I call a stored procedure it fails with following:

Login failed for user token-identified principal

When I debug locally with my own user everything works.
I have granted access with following SQL:
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.XX_InitRun TO [xx-int-xx-dev];

This is how I call the stored procedure:
public void XX_InitRun()
{            
   this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("[dbo].[XX_InitRun]");
}

Any suggestions how to troubleshoot or solve this?

does the managed identity has permission to execute stored procedure ? GRANT EXECUTE TO [<Managed Identity Name>]

Follow the instructions here.  If you can't connect, you probably don't have the contained database user created for the managed identity. eg:
CREATE USER [<Managed Identity Name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
Tutorial: Use a Windows VM system-assigned managed identity to access Azure SQL

All of that has been done, why I can get everything else to work but calling stored procedures.

"Login failed for user token-identified principal" that's a login failure.  So it's failing to even connect.  Are you sure it's attempting to connect to the correct database?

Yes. All other calls to the DB works perfectly fine. I suspect it is an error in the EF that does not work with managd identities and stored procedures.

Nope. That’s not it.  Try to produce a minimal repro, and you don’t find the problem add it to your question.
